# CSR matrix to dense matrix after using countvectorizer text extraction method on Quora Insincere questions classification

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am working on an Quora dataset of kaggle competition where I am using Countvecctorizer.

```
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 8000)
X = cv.fit_transform(processed)
```

After that I want to convert X(Sparse matrix) in to dense matrix, for converting this matrix to dense matrix i use both the method.

```
X.toarray()
X.todense()
```

In both case there occur an error
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTJS6.png)

How would i create a dense matrix from this sparse matrix?

Comment: We prefer a copy-n-paste of the error and traceback.  But in the case the image is clear - it's a memory error.  The equivalent dense array is too big for your memory.

Comment: Will you tell me the method to deal with sparse matrix for bigger data?